# Hibernate Select certain columns that are entity objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to use Spring Boot (and obviously I am a newbie) along with Hibernate.

```
 @Entity
    public class UserRole {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long userRoleId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
        private User user;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
        private Role role;
}
```

I am trying to retrieve only the List of User Objects without having to rely on a UserRole object List to take them.

I tried the following into my UserRoleRepository

```
@Query("select u.user from user_role u where u.role = :role")
public ArrayList<User> findByRoleQ(Role role);
```

When i tried the above query I got a missmatch mapping error When i tried to run it as follows

> 2018-01-27 18:14:12.299  WARN 10720 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'afdempUisuxAdminApplication':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRoleService';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userRoleServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'userRoleRepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userRoleRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract
>   java.util.ArrayList
>   org.afdemp.uisux.repository.UserRoleRepository.findByRoleQ(org.afdemp.uisux.domain.security.Role)!

What am I doing wrong and is there a way to make it return only the User column (thus User List)?

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426102/how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-object-associated-as-field-into-an-entity-class/48426768#48426768

Comment: Your entity is named UserRole, not user_role.