# Get only nested Object from MongoDB by Spring Data mongoDb or mongo template

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : "a9582f59-f52b-4fc8-84ab-cdd0bfb8dead",
    "_class" : "com.db.Category",
    "name" : "Cricket",
    "subCategories" : [
        {
            "name" : "Gloves",
            "creationDate" : NumberLong("1527404341099"),
            "modificationDate" : NumberLong("1527404341099")
        },
        {
            "name" : "Stumps",
            "creationDate" : NumberLong("1527404369882"),
            "modificationDate" : NumberLong("1527404369882")
        },
        {
            "name" : "Bat",
            "brandList" : [
                {
                    "name" : "MRF",
                    "productDetails" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "Bat 111",
                            "price" : "1224",
                            "imageUrlList" : [
                                "https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/gasports/1527792222680-Bat_111",
                                "https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/gasports/1527792228375-Bat_111"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "creationDate" : NumberLong("1527424021629"),
            "modificationDate" : NumberLong("1527424021629")
        }
    ],
    "creationDate" : NumberLong("1527404340938"),
    "modificationDate" : NumberLong("1527404340938")
}
```

This is Category Document. Category has subcategory,Subcategory has brands and Brand has products.

```
@Document(collection="productInfo")
public class Category extends BaseProductInfo<Category> {

@Id
private String uid;

private String name;

private List<SubCategory> subCategories;
```

//Getters ans setters..

Now I have to get only for specific subcategory or Brand or Product. For this currently I am doing iteration to get object.

Is there any way in Spring Data Mongo Repository to get nested Object ?

Comment: can you explain this statement of your. "Now I have to get only for specific subcategory or Brand or Product". And also can you give an example

Comment: e.g . I want to update productDetails of "Bat 111" product.  For this I find category. After getting category,I iterate through all subcategories till i Find "Bat" and same for Product.

Answer (score -2):

You can write a method like this in your Category Repository class

```
Category findBySubCategories_BrandList_ProductDetails_Name(String name)
```

Just pass the product name you want to fetch. spring-data-mongodb will formulate the query based on your meethod name and fetch the documents matching the query.

Comment: Category findBySubCategories_BrandList_ProductDetails_Name(String name) 
This will give me Category Object and I need only ProductDetailsObject .e.g. 
ProductDetails findBySubCategories_BrandList_ProductDetails_Name(String name)
Can I get nested Object (Product details) of Parent Object (Category) ?

Comment: have a look at Projections. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#projections. Check out my answer here regarding the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426102/how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-object-associated-as-field-into-an-entity-class/48426768#48426768

Comment: I have already tried Mongo Repository 
@Query(value = "{ 'name' : ?0, 'subCategories.name' : ?1, 'subCategories.brandList.name' : ?2 }", fields = "{ 'subCategories.name' : 1,'subCategories.brandList.name' : 2 }")
    Category findCategoryByCatAndSubCatAndBrandName(String categoryName, String subcategoryName, String brandName);

This results me Category Object not only Brand Object.

Comment: As i stated above, you need to use projections